# Unable to ng serve second project in angular 7 application

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have recently added second project to the existing angular 7 application. The Idea is to have more than one project in the work space.I used the angular CLI to create the second project

```
ng generate application my-other-app
```

project has be created under projects folder but when I tried to ng server the application I am getting the following error msg

```
ng serve --project="my-other-app"

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with @angular-devkit/build-angular is not updated to latest version. Older version has not support for es5.